# Bash redirect 'interactive' output to special file

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, tty, pv

I want to redirect e.g. the output i.e. the progress bar of `pv` to `/dev/tty1`.

```
 ...  | pv -perts 100G |  ... 2> /dev/tty1
```

But what I get is whenever the progress bar updates it does so in an new line while the old status remains in the line above.

Is there a way to enable it to refresh? I've heard of `col` but I assume it will print after the output has finished, which is not suitable for visually tracking the progress, of course.

Comment: Are you saying that in tty1 you get multiple lines of output...one new line for each refresh from `pv`? I'm not 100% sure if that's what you're describing but I answered assuming it is. If you mean something else please clarify. Copy in some output text or add a screen grab or whatever is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm assuming tty and pty will behave the same. I only have access to the latter right now.*

Try this...

```
... | pv --force -perts 100G 2> /dev/tty1 | ...
```

In my testing the progress bar renders normally in the terminal associated with `/dev/tty1` even though I'm running it from a different terminal.

(I had to add `--force` even though the `pv` man page says it's only necessary if standard error is not pointing to a terminal. I used pseudo-terminals so perhaps it doesn't consider them the same. Leave it off if things work without it.)

---

An example run through...

```
cat file_250M | pv --force -perts 250M 2> /dev/pty7 | wc
```

"Local" terminal:

```
0       0 262144000
```

/dev/pty7 terminal (a single, changing line):

```
0:00:06 [36.7MiB/s] [======================================================================>] 100%
```

Comment: Yes you are right, it was my fault not noticing that it come from curl which was also running. Pv alone works fine. I fixed it with curl -s because luckily I don't need the curl output.